# Autolayout of UITableViewCell doesn't work when selecting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

Autolayout of my UITableViewCell works as expected when viewing, but when I selecting a row, the UI will break, and the height of this cell will also back to default value.

For cell-related code, I just followed this tutorial "[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)"

Unfortunately, this tutorial doesn't cover selection part of UITableViewCell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell = ...
    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:MyViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the constraints in the storyboard? could you add more details about them? Also, you should not need to call `[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];`

Comment: If you are targeting iOS8, you don't need `heightForRowAtIndexPath`at all. If you are targeting iOS7, don't return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, but look in the page you linked to how to set up an offscreen cell..